# How to add SOAP headers to a SOAP request using JAX-WS?

Tags: soap, jax-ws, soapheader

We need to consume webservices developed by other team. Using `JAX-WS` for generating the webservices. We are using *wsimport* to generate the client side stubs.

The problem is that i need to pass the following info as a header along with the SOAP body:

```xml
<soapenv:Header>
    <ns1:HeaderData xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
                    xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/esb/data_type/HeaderData/v1">
        <ChannelIdentifier>ABC</ChannelIdentifier>
    </ns1:HeaderData>
</soapenv:Header>
```

We are using:

```
BindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(
    BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
    serviceConfig.getServiceEndPoint()
);
```

to set the endpoint.

Can anyone suggest how to pass headers with request?

Thanks,
VK

Answer (score 13):

use param `header = true` of `@WebParam` annotation

```
@WebMethod
@WebResult String method(
      @WebParam String anotherParam
      @WebParam(header = true, mode = Mode.OUT) Holder<String> headerParam)
```

`header = true, mode = Mode.OUT` means that param `headerParam` will be only in output in header.
If you want this this param in input and in output, make `Mode.INOUT`

Answer (score 7):

I had to add user credentials into the header so I made it like this:

```
private void modifyRequest(String username, String password) {
    UserCredentials authHeader = new UserCredentials();
    authHeader.setUsername(username);
    authHeader.setPassword(password);
    ArrayList<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>(1);
    try {
        Header soapHeader = new Header(new QName(TQIntegrationV2.TQIntegrationV2Soap.getNamespaceURI(), "UserCredentials"), authHeader, new JAXBDataBinding(UserCredentials.class));
        headers.add(soapHeader);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception trying to serialize header: {}", ex);
    }
    ((BindingProvider) proxy).getRequestContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);
}
```

And everything works fine. Every call to web service comes with username and password passed to this header. You can easily change this to work in your case.

**EDIT**

The code above is using `CXF` API to modify header. I have also done this using `JAX-WS`. It does almost the same, modifies the header to add the user credentials:

```
public class MyHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyHandler.class);

    private String username;

    private String password;

    /**
     * Handles SOAP message. If SOAP header does not already exist, then method will created new SOAP header. The
     * username and password is added to the header as the credentials to authenticate user. If no user credentials is
     * specified every call to web service will fail.
     *
     * @param context SOAP message context to get SOAP message from
     * @return true
     */
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        try {
            SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();
            SOAPHeader header = message.getSOAPHeader();
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
            if (header == null) {
                header = envelope.addHeader();
            }
            QName qNameUserCredentials = new QName("https://your.target.namespace/", "UserCredentials");
            SOAPHeaderElement userCredentials = header.addHeaderElement(qNameUserCredentials);

            QName qNameUsername = new QName("https://your.target.namespace/", "Username");
            SOAPHeaderElement username = header.addHeaderElement(qNameUsername );
            username.addTextNode(this.username);
            QName qNamePassword = new QName("https://your.target.namespace/", "Password");
            SOAPHeaderElement password = header.addHeaderElement(qNamePassword);
            password.addTextNode(this.password);

            userCredentials.addChildElement(username);
            userCredentials.addChildElement(password);

            message.saveChanges();
            //TODO: remove this writer when the testing is finished
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            message.writeTo(new StringOutputStream(writer));
            LOGGER.debug("SOAP message: \n" + writer.toString());
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occurred while adding credentials to SOAP header.", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occurred while writing message to output stream.", e);
        }
        return true;
    }

    //TODO: remove this class after testing is finished
    private static class StringOutputStream extends OutputStream {

        private StringWriter writer;

        public StringOutputStream(StringWriter writer) {
            this.writer = writer;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            writer.write(b);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        LOGGER.debug("handleFault has been invoked.");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
        LOGGER.debug("close has been invoked.");
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        LOGGER.debug("getHeaders has been invoked.");
        return null;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

And I define this handler in `Spring` configuration like this:

```
<bean id="soapHandler" class="your.package.MyHandler">
    <property name="username" value="testUser"/>
    <property name="password" value="testPassword"/>
</bean>

<jaxws:client "...">
    <jaxws:handlers>
        <ref bean="soapHandler"/>
    </jaxws:handlers>
</jaxws:client>
```

All you need to do is to implement `SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>` interface, override its methods and then you can do what ever you want with a `SOAP` message.

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you post the fully qualified name of Header class. Just want to find whether it is from jaxws api.

Comment: Header is not from JAX-WS its from CXF, I have edited the answer how to modify the header in JAX-WS.