# How to get xml request and xml response from netbeans client to ws

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

I have created web-service client to the existing service in netbeans, and ide makes all in oop style correctly, but I need to log xml request and response to and from service, how to log these information?

Comment: Which stack of web services you are using? Is it JAX-WS, CXF....? How are exposing your web service endpoint?

Comment: I use jax-ws, web-service is deployed on glassfish

Comment: Netbeans generate all code, and I do not know how to get xml data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of logging the request and response of your web service, you need to create your custom soap handler for `JAX-WS` which implements `SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>` interface.

The method to do anything you like with a message is `handleMessage(SAOPMessageContext messageContext)`. From the message context you will be able to get the SOAP message and log it.

See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388552/how-to-add-soap-header-to-soap-request-using-jaxws/12392641#12392641) how to implement SOAP handler interface and override `handleMessage` method for the specific requirements.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945618/tracing-xml-request-responses-with-jax-ws) leads to what you are trying to achieve.
Take a look at [this article](http://jax-ws.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html). It might be helpful as well. If you are not able to set up your handler, come back with more specific problem.